# Firebase messaging can not receive notification when app close ( React Native )

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification

I have an app that using push notification from Firebase.
In my app i have implement 2 method:

```
        firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {        
                senName = message.data.senderName;
                senUid = message.data.senderUid;
                const notification = new 
                firebase.notifications.Notification()
                    .setNotificationId('notificationId')
                    .setTitle(message.data.title)
                    .setBody(message.data.body)
                    .android.setChannelId('channel_id_foreground')
                    .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher');
                firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification)
        });
```

and

```
        firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
            // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
            const action = notificationOpen.action;
            // Get information about the notification that was opened
            const notification = notificationOpen.notification;             
        });
```

if my app run in foreground and background, it will show notification correctly. If I do nothing and just close app it can not show the notification.

But when in foreground if i tap on the notification it will run to onNotificationOpened method, and then I close app by swipe out, it still show notification normally.

So it just show notification in case close/swipe app if I have taped on the notification before.

Anybody can help me ?

Comment: Have you tried increasing notification priority?

Answer (score 4):

### Android

For an app to get a notification while it is closed (or in the background), it needs to register a background task that handles those messages, and then opens the app if necessary.

To create this task, you use react-native's `AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask`:

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', handler);
```

Where the handler is a function that returns a message handler:

```
const handler = () => message => {
    // Do something with the message
}
```

To handle actions (on Android), you need another task:

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationAction', actionHandler);
```

Where handler is again something like:

```
const actionHandler = () => message => {
    // Do something with message
}
```

For this whole thing to work, you need to update your manifest with the following:

```
<service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />
<receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationActionReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.BackgroundAction"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationActionsService"/>
```

The documentation on setting up messaging in the background is [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/messaging/receiving-messages), and for actions is [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/android-actions).

### iOS

On iOS, you can't send a data-only notification, so you'll have to include the title and text in the notification itself (Server side).

If you do that, then your phone will display the notification automatically, and you'll only have to handle the notification being opened.

### Both

You can also do things when the notification is displayed:

```
firebase.notifications().onNotificationDisplayed(notification => { ... })
```

Or when it is received by the phone:

```
firebase.notifications().onNotification(notification => { ... })
```

If you want to get the notification that triggered the app opening, use the following:

```
firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification().then(notification => { ... })
```

The documentation for all of this can be found [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/receiving-notifications).

Comment: Kraylog,

First many thanks for your useful advise. I have registered a background task as your comment but the notification do not show in case close/swipe app unless taped on the notification received before.

At this time I just use data-only notification and implement on Android. I have tried use notification with title and body, but in the background don't now why after received notification, my app is going to be crashed. However according to your answer, data-only can not work on iOS right ? So I need to try to use notification message again.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, how can I send something to `RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage `?

Answer (score 0):

In version 6 we need to add

```js
// index.js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import App from './App';

// Register background handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => App);
```

The handler **must return a promise** once your logic has completed to free up device resources. It must not attempt to update any UI (e.g. via state) - you can however perform network requests, update local storage etc.

source: [rnfirebase.io documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#background--quit-state-messages)